# Python: Passing and updating default parameters idoms

Tags: python

If I wrap a function into a bigger function but I still want to have access to all the parameters of the inner function is customary to do:

```
def bigFun(par1, **kwargs):
    innerFun(**kwargs)
```

Now, if I want to provide default values in the wrapper function and still have let the user to **override** these value I can do:

```
def bigFun(par1, **kwargs):
    default_kwargs = dict(keyX=valueX, keyY=valueY, ...)
    default_kwargs.update(**kwargs)
    kwargs = default_kwargs
    innerFun(**kwargs)
```

which I don't particularly like.

It seems a common enough situation to me.

Any other idiom do people use in this case?

Answer (score 2):

```
def bigFun(par1, **kwargs):
    kwargs[keyX] = kwargs.get(keyX, valueX)
    innerFun(**kwargs)
```

or for multiple pairs:

```
def bigFun(par1, **kwargs):
    for k,v in [('key1', 'val1'), ('key2', 'val2')]:
        kwargs[k] = kwargs.get(k, v)
    innerFun(**kwargs)
```

Comment: My point is: what if I have several default arguments? Do I need a new line for each parameter?

Comment: @user2304916, you have constant number of lines regardless of the number of default arguments. How much better can it get?

Comment: Now that you added the multiple pairs version it looks interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the keyword notation in your wrapper function for default, and pass them explicitely to the inner one:

```
def bigFun(arg, def_arg='foo', other_arg='bar', **kwargs):
    innerFun(def_arg=def_arg, other_arg=other_arg, **kwargs)
```

Comment: but then you need to change the inner function?

Comment: if it already accepted keywords arguments, then no. You just have to specify the right argument names when calling it.

Comment: Your solution works and is very reasonable in some cases. In my case however I don't like that you "pollute" the signature of bigFun only because you add a new default value and, secondly, for each new default value you have to write it twice (once in bigFun and once in innerFun call).

Comment: @user2304916 How else would the user know what to type to override the inner function's defaults?

Comment: Just mentioning in bigFun docstring what innerFun you call. If you are wrapping a very well known function  with tons of argument and very good documentation (think about `plot` from matplotlib) makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could use setdefault

```
def bigFun(par1, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault(keyX, valueX)
    kwargs.setdefault(keyY, valueY)
    innerFun(**kwargs)
```